# Integrating framework in mac app

Tags: objective-c, frameworks

In my app I am using objc-appscript framework. What is the real difference between compiling it, linking to it and then copying inside app as private framework, or just adding all its code to project and compiling to one binary? Or shorter: what do I get by using private framework instead of compiling its code into my binary?

Answer (score 1):

Benefits:

1. Code modularizing .
2. Runtime behavior --- you give fix only to you app or only to the par of framework.
3. Framework -- can be shared by multiple application.